# Is the $L^p$ space of tensors complete?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

On a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, let $\mathcal L^p(M,k)$ denote the space of measurable $k$-tensors $T$ (i.e., the coordinate components in any chart are Lebesgue measurable) for which the norm 
$$||T||_p=\int_M |T|^p\,d\mu_g,\quad |T|=\sqrt{T_{i_1\cdots i_k}T^{i_1\cdots i_k} }$$
is finite. Is this space complete?

In compact case, I obtained an affirmative answer on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064539/on-a-manifold-is-the-lp-space-of-vector-fields-complete), but the answer does not seem to carry over to the general case. The book by Chavel, *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry*, seems to claim this is true. He offers no proof.

Comment: Does any step of the standard proof that $L^p$ is complete fail here?

Comment: @WillSawin Maybe nothing fails. I thought surely one couldn't use monotone/dominated convergence, but perhaps I didn't understand the proof for $L^p$ as well as I should. I have to carefully check this now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way to approach such questions using Grothendieck's completeness.  Suppose that you have a complete topological vector space and an absolutely convex bounded closed subset thereof.  Then the span of the latter is a Banach space with its Minkowski functional as norm. In your case, you can take the space of (equivalence classes of) measurable functions with its natural structure as a complete, metrisable tvs and the unit ball of your space of $L^p$-type tensors.  A suitable reference for the Grothendieck result would be his notes on topological vector spaces which is available in english translation or the monograph of Schaefer.